# How can I implement the typestate pattern based on a discriminator?

Tags: rust, types

I have a use-case in mind where I query a database by handing it a `Device<T>` where `T: Counter`.  I can imagine how the consuming API looks:

```rs
fn get_counts<T: Counter>(dev: Device<T>) -> Vec<Count> {}
```

But when trying to implement `Device`, I can't find a pattern that satisfied the compiler.  I want to do something like:

```rs
struct Device<T> {
  id: i64,
  addr: i64,
  _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> Device<T> {
  fn new(id: i64, addr: i64, kind: i64) -> Self {
    match kind {
      // where MyType1 implements Counter
      0 => Self { id, addr, _marker: PhantomData<MyType1> },
      // where MyType2 implements SomeDefaultTrait
      1 => Self { id, addr, _marker: PhantomData<MyType2> },
      _ => todo!(),
    }
  }
}
```

And this complains that type `Device<MyType1>` is not a `Device<T>`.  How do I move forward with implementing this pattern that satisfies the compiler?  I couldn't find any examples that implement typestate based off a discriminator to give me a resulting type.

Comment: In my imagination, I would return a `Device<T> where T: Counter OR DefaultTrait` instead of `Self`, but this doesn't exist to my knowledge.

Comment: You can't return multiple different types from a function without dynamic dispatch.

Comment: You may be able to split this into separate `impl` blocks.

Comment: I could use dynamic dispatch, but how do I say "this is a `Box<dyn Counter OR dyn Device>` @PitaJ

Comment: With a trait that you implement for all types you want to return. It can be an empty marker trait, or you add the methods to get concrete types if they match.

Comment: The other alternative is to return an enum with a variant for each subtype instead.

Comment: @cafce25 you know, I might have been overthinking this.  So use a supertrait for the _creation_ of the `Device` and have the API take one of its sub-traits?

Comment: But a supertrait requires me to implement both traits, which is not the behavior I want @cafce25

Comment: I didn't say anything about **super**-traits. Imo the best way is to [split it up](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3b9f5d1c624f3dde96fdf9956b879f17) as PitaJ suggested.

Comment: @cafce25 That _looks_ good, but how do I create different types based on the discriminator?  That's what I'm really struggling with here.

Comment: For the most part @cafce25 for the most part.  It involved a lot of boilerplate that only gets worse with more variants, but I was able to box the structs in one big enum in order to create the proper variants with trait bounds.